# How to run ssis package in Microsoft Fabric?

Tags: ssis, microsoft-fabric

As you now microsoft relaesed a trail version of fabric and in fabric we dont have ssis ir in fabric data factory or any direct ssis integration.
If i want to run ssis package in Fabric data factory pipeline what i can do?

I am trying to submit a question and expecting answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a SSIS package in MS Fabric, it isn't supported. You'll have to use Azure Data Factory SH/IR and push the data to OneLake, Lakehouse or SQL Warehouse.

Also see
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Data-Pipelines/Lift-and-Shift-SSIS-packages-using-Fabric-Data-Factory/m-p/3256857